# Where is the value "Item owner: sitecore\smith" from "Quick Info" living in back-end SQL tables?

Tags: sql-database, sitecore-query

I'm unable yet to locate a particular "Item owner:  **sitecore\smith**" value I see well-and-alive in Content Editor "Quick Info" of an item, but not in the SQL Server backend tables.

I often pull a convenient SELECT query over the:

- Items
- VersionedFields
- unVersionedFields

tables, but this particular field VALUE doesn't seem to live there. I went to other tables like History, but still didn't find it there either.

To be noted is that it's a content that is created from an importing agent automation from a CSV file. So the __owner "sitecore\smith" is from the developer under which the import agent executes, rather that the real Sitecore end-user. But does it really matter as to simply find where this value "sitecore\smith" lives in the backend tables..

Thank you!

Comment: sitecore\smith is a user, but the master database doesn't contain user information, the Core database handles that functionality.  Are you just trying to determine where information for sitecore\smith exists?

Comment: Thank you Dylan, I'm trying to determine where the "sitecore\smith" VALUE, of presumably the __owner field came from, on the "Quick Info" of an item. When I lookup the item in SQL Server versionedFields table (and unversionedFields, sharedFields tables , I find __created_by, but there's no __owner field for this particular item. The mystery deepens further: I do a View Source in the browser, and see, nested in <td> "Item Owner:"  => sitecore\admin.

Comment: PS: thanks a ton for your wonderful Youtube workshops!  I've been iterating on these recently and this has been really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`Item owner` is a versioned field of an item. You can see it in the `Security` section:

[image]

[image]

If you want to find that value for given item in a Sitecore database, you can use a query like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    [VersionedFields]
  WHERE 
    FieldId = '52807595-0F8F-4B20-8D2A-CB71D28C6103'
AND
  ItemId = '110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marek, yes this is the query that should surface it up, but unfortunately doesn't. And strangely enough, I do a View Source on the "Quick Info" page, and I see "Item Owner:"  ...  "sitecore\admin"  while the page shows "sitecore\smith".. The mystery deepens.  I'm thinking of 2 possibilities: 1) it could come from an internal Sitecore/Lucene index, and not from the SQL Server tables and although both should be synced they are not.
Or 2) it could be the "Item Owner" of a bucket and/or parent content. But this is unlikely. Or this is yet another table like versionedFields that I missed